# norm of vector + element of subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed vector space, and let $x \in X$ be such that $||x|| \leq 1$. Let $U$ be a subspace of $X$. Then apparently one can always find a vector $u \in U$ such that $||x+u||=1$. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Let $u_0$ be a nonzero vector in $U$. Show that $\phi(\alpha) = ||x + \alpha u_0||$ is a continuous function from $\mathbf R$ to $\mathbf R$.

Comment: I see that the function should be continuous, and then one would apply the extreme value theorem, but you have $\phi(0) = ||x|| \leq 1$, but you'd still need some $\alpha$ such that $\phi(\alpha) \geq 1$ for the extreme value theorem to apply.

Comment: The norm axioms imply $\phi(\alpha) \to \infty$ as $\alpha \to \pm \infty$.

Comment: Umberto P.: Perfect, thanks.